# How to hook in \input{foo/bar} and not \input{bar}?

Tags: input, lthooks

Consider the following root document that imports two different files named `bar` and uses the `file/before/...` hook.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook { file/before/bar } {
  \iow_term:n { ****~HOOKED }
}
\input{bar}
\input{foo/bar}
\end{document}
```

After typesetting, the terminal reads `**** HOOKED` **twice**, one for each `\input`.

How can I hook in `\input{foo/bar}` but not in `\input{bar}`, while still importing both documents ?

I am guessing some kind of solution based on `\CurrentFilePath` but it seems overcomplicated.

Comment: It was a design decision to ignore paths when executing file hooks.  A file hook is identified by the file base name and extension only (thus `\CurrentFilePath` is provided, if the user so needs). The solution proposed by Ulrike is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

What is overcomplicated in checking \CurrentFilePath?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook { file/before/bar.tex } {
  \str_if_in:NnT\CurrentFilePath{bib}
   {
    \iow_term:n { ****~HOOKED }
   } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\input{bar}
\input{bib/bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The files are named `bar` not `bar.tex`.
Complications come from an eventually following `\input{bib1/bar}`, and worst `\input{bib/../bar}`.

Comment: I know that you used `bar`, but I'm on windows and it is easier for me to test with files with extensions. You can naturally extend the test -- including using regex if needed. Beside this: file hooks are nice to handle foreign files loaded e.g. inside some package. But if you own the files it is much easier if you add the hook directly to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept to take the full path into account, not just the last component. We both add or remove code from hooks. We assume that `bar.tex`, `foo/bar.tex` and `foo.tex` are available.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \myLog #1 {
  \iow_term:x { ****~#1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\myAddToFileBefore { m } {
  \group_begin:
  \regex_set:Nn \l_tmpa_regex { \A \s* (?:(.*)\/)? \s* (.*?) \s* \Z }
  \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \l_tmpa_regex { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq {
    \cs_set:Nn \my_tmpa:nn {
      \AddToHook { file/before/##2 } [ my/file/before/#1 ] {
        \str_if_eq:VnT \CurrentFilePath { ##1 } {
          \myLog{HOOKED~#1 }
        }
      }
    }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_tmpa:nn { xx }
    \my_tmpa:xx { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 2 } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 3 }
  } {
    \myLog{Bad argument:~#1 }
  }
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand\myRemoveFromFileBefore { m } {
  \regex_set:Nn \l_tmpa_regex { \A \s* (?:(.*)\/)? \s* (.*?) \s* \Z }
  \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \l_tmpa_regex { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq {
    \RemoveFromHook { file/before/\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq 3 } [ my/file/before/#1 ]
  } {
    \myLog{Bad argument:~#1 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
NO INPUT
\myLog{EXPECTED NO HOOK}
\input{bar.tex}        % (./bar.tex)
\input{foo/bar.tex}    % (./foo/bar.tex)
\input{foo.tex}        % (./foo.tex)
\myLog{EXPECTED HOOKED bar.tex}
\myAddToFileBefore{bar.tex}
\input{bar.tex}        % **** HOOKED bar.tex (./bar.tex)
\input{foo/bar.tex}    % (./foo/bar.tex)
\input{foo.tex}        % (./foo.tex)
\myLog{EXPECTED HOOKED bar.tex and foo/bar.tex}
\myAddToFileBefore{foo/bar.tex}
\input{bar.tex}        % **** HOOKED bar.tex (./bar.tex)
\input{foo/bar.tex}    % **** HOOKED foo/bar.tex (./foo/bar.tex)
\input{foo.tex}        % (./foo.tex)
\myLog{EXPECTED HOOKED foo/bar.tex}
\myRemoveFromFileBefore{bar.tex}
\input{bar.tex}        % **** (./bar.tex)
\input{foo/bar.tex}    % **** HOOKED foo/bar.tex (./foo/bar.tex)
\input{foo.tex}        % (./foo.tex)
\myLog{EXPECTED NO HOOK}
\myRemoveFromFileBefore{foo/bar.tex}
\input{bar.tex}        % (./bar.tex)
\input{foo/bar.tex}    % (./foo/bar.tex)
\input{foo.tex}        % (./foo.tex)
\end{document}
```

**Explanation and comments:**

1. `\myAddToFileBefore` adds some code logging to the terminal,
   to be executed before file input only if the current path is the expected one
2. `\myRemoveFromFileBefore` removes that same piece of code.
3. The "trick" is to use the label in `\AddToHook` and `\RemoveFromHook`.
4. We then `\input` both `bar.tex` after we either add code or remove code just for one of them
5. the comment on each line reads the corresponding terminal output
6. Some path normalization may occur after the regex extraction.
7. `foo.tex` is never hooked.